# iOS: how to refresh a ViewController with new data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reload, viewcontroller

I want to use the same ViewController that upon click on a button changes "data" on the display. It's going to be used for a quiz app, so i want the view controller for the questions to run the same logic but with (of course) different questions and answers when the user selects an answer. I read some about views and subviews and also about the viewDidLoad function, but i can't seem to find "best practices" in this matter.

Thankful for any help!

Olof

Comment: You need to spend more time going through some Apple samples and reading references on the internet.

Comment: Don't think of view as a webpage, there is no refreshing. Just update any label, textbox, button, etc.. they will just reflect there new state directly.

Comment: Useful information, rckoenes. Thank you for the input, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this: create a model of your data and put a list of model items in a list. When the user clicks on the button, update your UI elements with the next item in the list. Here it is some code to think about:

```
@implementation YourViewController {
    NSArray *items;
    NSUInteger itemCount;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  itemCount = 0;
  // load your items
}

- (IBAction)nextButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
   itemCount++;
   // check array boundaries
   // update UI
}

@end
```

Comment: Seems a bit vague.  Given the OP is a beginner, by the look of it, I doubt this answer will provide any help at all.